# Xamarin Android: Type or namespace name 'ViewModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Arch.Lifecycle'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm

I added the Android.Arch.Lifecycles.Core and Android.Arch.Lifecycles.Runtime libraries through NuGet in an attempt to duplicate the tutorial [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android-support/ViewModel/).  I also downloaded that code itself.

However, in my app, I get the error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ViewModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Arch.Lifecycle' (are you missing an assembly reference?) no matter what I try.

Loading the downloaded code and picking through it doesn't throw the same error.

I tried moving it around various folders in the project and trying to use Intellisense to see if it was renamed.

The only error is in this line:

```
public class NewsViewModel : Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel
```

It should inherit the ViewModel class for MVVM development, but the error is thrown and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel/

Answer (score 1):

While adding the NuGet packages for near every Xamarin.Android.Arch package, ViewModel is not included in Xamarin.Android.Arch.VieWModel. Right-click Go To Definition in the project I downloaded showed that, for some reason, it's defined in Xamarin.Android.Arch.Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Extensions/1.1.1.1